# jQuery Date Picker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, font-size

I am using following attached date picker.
http://rapidshare.com/files/417385026/jQuery_Date_Picker.zip
http://www.2shared.com/file/d2NK63P-/jQuery_Date_Picker.html

Problem is if i don't use font-size tag in the body of the HTML page date picker size becomes too big .

I tried using Font-size tag with the div/table/td inside which i put the input box which has date picker but it doesn't work, it works only with body to reduce the datepicker size.

Please let me know how i can reduce the size of this date picker without actually reducing the font size of the whole page.

Here are screen shots

With font size tag in body

img835.imageshack.us/i/92688528.jpg

Without font size tag in body

img833.imageshack.us/i/48042121.jpg

Thank You.

Comment: which datePicker is that? (sorry, I won't donwload it ;) )

Comment: the images are now 1x1. Can't you tell us where did you learn about that datepicker? give a link to a project page?

Comment: Link: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.

In the jquery-ui.css, font can be changed here

```
.ui-widget { font-family:Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1.1em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem with the jQuery ui date picker (I'm assuming that's what you're using, but no-one's going to want to download your zip). I had to set the `body` `font-size` property to something like 10 or 11px for it to look decent.

Comment: I cannot set the font size at the body level, as my page setting/font change which i don't want. I want to apply font size at the div/table level but it's not working with this jquery. http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year